# Hitting a return at password prompt in expect script instead of sending password

Tags: bash, expect

I am trying to have an expect script inside a bash to login to a router, execute a command and store output in a text file.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
FQDN=$1
LogFile=/tmp/Router_${FQDN}.txt
> $LogFile
expect -d  <<EOF > $LogFile
set timeout 20
set FQDN [lindex $argv 0]
set Username "user"
set Password "***$$$"
spawn ssh $Username@$FQDN
expect "*assword:"
send "$Password\r"
expect "#"
send "some command\r"
expect "#"
send "exit\r"
sleep 1
exit
expect eof
EOF
cat $LogFile
```

I am getting the below error message.

```
system personnel  =\r\r\n= may provide the evidence of such monitoring to law enforcement officials.    =\r\r\n=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==\r\r\npassword: "
send: sending "\n" to { exp6 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "#"? no
password:
Enter old password:
```

Based on the error it appears that script is hitting the {return} key "\r" which is not to be sent at password prompt.

I don't have a return once i ssh. Not sure where i am going wrong.

---

This is my expect script which is working fine. Its only when i code this inside a bash script its failing.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 20
set FQDN [lindex $argv 0]
set Username "user"
set Password "***$$$"
spawn ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" $Username@$FQDN
expect "*assword: "
send "$Password\r"
expect "#"
send "some command\r"
expect "#"
send "exit\r"
sleep 1
exit
```

-Abhi

Comment: Your password has expired on the remote system, so it's asking you to change your password. But the expect script doesn't seem to be prepared for that.

Comment: Obligatory suggestion to enable public-key authentication instead of using `expect` to authenticate an SSH session.

Comment: @Barmar NO, when i manually login, i get in fine. Also i have an expect script too (not inside my shell script) and it works fine.

Comment: @chepner the router for now doesn't support key based authentication.

Comment: `set FQDN [lindex $argv 0]` means that the hostname should be an argument to `expect`, but you're not supplying an argument.

Comment: Shouldn't `$user` be `$Username`?

Comment: I think the problem is that it's never getting the `#` prompt that it expects, so the 20 second timeout is being reached and it sends `some command` anyway.

Comment: @Barmar,  I am supplying the argument while running my bash script - ./router_command.sh "routerHostName" and i can see that script is getting into the router till password prompt and failing.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry i had the code wrong while opening this thread. I have corrected it now. I am passing the correct variable in my script too.

Comment: @Barmar, The prompt # is correct once i login to the device after entering the password, the problem is at the password prompt itself at which the script i believe is sending a return instead of password variable value.

Comment: The output shows it sending `Enter old password:`. I don't know why, but it's sending that instead of sending the `#` prompt.

Comment: @Barmar spawn ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" $Username@$FQDN where FQDN is my argument being passed to expect script from bash. I can see the substitution being happening when i run. Thanks for all your replies so far.

Comment: @Barmar, i manually tried to replicate this issue. When doing manually whenever i hit a return at the password prompt, the next prompt that is being provided is Enter old password: . So the issue is a return being hit at the password prompt from my script.

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a here-doc, variables like `$Username` and `$Password` are being expanded by the shell, so they're not seen as literals for `Expect` to expand. Since those shell variables aren't set anywhere, they're being expanded to null strings. As a result, it's executing `ssh @$FQDN` and sending an empty password.

You need to escape the `$` so that `Expect` can process them.

You also don't need the `set FQDN` line in the Expect script, since you're using the shell variable for that.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
FQDN=$1
LogFile=/tmp/Router_${FQDN}.txt
> $LogFile
expect -d  <<EOF > $LogFile
set timeout 20
set Username "user"
set Password "***$$$"
spawn ssh \$Username@$FQDN
expect "*assword:"
send "\$Password\r"
expect "#"
send "some command\r"
expect "#"
send "exit\r"
sleep 1
exit
expect eof
EOF
cat $LogFile
```

Or you could set them as shell variables, just like `FQDN`.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
FQDN=$1
Username=user
Password="***$$$"
LogFile=/tmp/Router_${FQDN}.txt
> $LogFile
expect -d  <<EOF > $LogFile
set timeout 20
spawn ssh $Username@$FQDN
expect "*assword:"
send "$Password\r"
expect "#"
send "some command\r"
expect "#"
send "exit\r"
sleep 1
exit
expect eof
EOF
cat $LogFile
```

Comment: Thank You. That did the trick. I escaped my password which also has dollars in it, but missed escaping expect $'s. Thanks again.

Comment: You could also just have the shell script run the expect script from a file instead of using a here-doc.